Verify Bézout theorem for two curves (projective closures)
Consider the affine curves $y^2=x^3+x^2$ and $y^2+2x^2+3x+1=0$. I would like to verify Bézout's theorem for the projective closures of these affine curves.

I have obtained $$C:y^2z=x^3+x^2z$$
$$B:y^2+2x^2+3xz+z^2=0.$$
In order to find the intersection points, first I will set $z=1$:
This gives me $$y^2=x^3+x^2 \;(1)\\y^2+2x^2+3x+1=0\; (2).$$
If I substitute equation (1) in equation (2) I get $$(x^3+x^2)+2x^2+3x+1=0,$$ which implies $x=-1$. But I'm cannot see how to go any further and determine the intersection points given $z=1$.
If I substitute $x=-1$ in equation (1), this implies $y=0$; but I'm not really sure if my work so far correct. I presume
that the point of intersection should be $(-1:0:1)$, but then again, I could be wrong.

For the points with $z=0,$ I obtain
$$0=x^3\\y^2+2x^2=0.$$
This gives me $x=y=0$, which implies $(x:y:z)=(0:0:0)$; and  this is not a valid point.
Is my work so far coorect?

So you see that $z = 1$ already provides an intersection point (but has multiplicity to be calculated). I think there are no more intersection points.

Is there some reason why you suspect something is wrong here? Everything here looks fine - I'm not really sure why you're posting this question on MSE.

@HankScorpio Well, unfortunately I haven't been able to attend the last lectures in which this material was covered, so I had to study my professor notes by myself. That's why I wasn't 100% sure if my work was correct.
